# Colorbox ajax + colorpicker plugin

Tags: php, jquery, colorbox

I'm currently making a form which is opened via colorbox's ajax feature. On my form i would like to make one of the input fields react on a jquery plugin (colorpicker), but it wont apply to the input field. I've tried to apply the script ( on the main page (where i load the ajax colorbox), and on the page that i get by ajax, but without luck.

The only thing i have to do in the plugin, is to load the js file and set the input's id="color". It isn't working as intended.

I've searched google dry for a solution to this problem.

Hope anybody has a solution to this problem!

**UPDATE:**

I use this in my headtag to initialize the jquery plugin (ColorPicker)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscolor.js"></script>
```

This is the function i call on Colorbox

```
jQuery(".ajax").colorbox({onComplete:function(){}});
```

The button where i execute the ajax function

```
<a class="ajax cboxElement" title="Settings for '.$load_all_polls->poll_title.'" href="edit.php?poll_id='.$load_all_polls->poll_id.'">Indstillinger</a>
```

Button with ajax call works fine!

And the inputfield which ColorPicker should respond to (inside the ajax call)

```
<input class="color" value="<?php echo $poll->bg_color; ?>" name="bg_color">
```

Again, the problem is that ColorPicker loads through my (DOM tree?) before the Ajax is called, therefore ColorPicker wont recognize the inputfield in the ajax call.

What to do ? :)

Regards,
Mathias

Comment: explain it further and post the code you've tried. That'll help others to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

The input field is loaded after page load via ajax. So `colorpicker` can not able to bind event to this newly loaded element. You should use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for attaching event to input field.

Comment: I've read the delegate function through, and I'm having a hard time understanding how i get it to read the input field, when i get the ajax file open. Sorry maybe i misunderstand something? :)

Comment: @MathiasFyrstJakobsen - What do you mean by **text field should react to colorpicker** ? Do you want to get color value in it or change text fields color, font color etc ?

Comment: @MathiasFyrstJakobsen - post the code what you've tried so far. That'll definitely explain question further.